# best way to store/save downloaded images in Android which is better for offline mode and sync?

Tags: java, android, performance

There are several ways images can be stored and there are many ideas about it. Mostly I have an app mostly a bit similar to google drive where user uploads, delete and download but using aws server. Currently everytime the app is opened I don't want to connect to server but want a offline backup which slowly syncs with server. I just want to know which is the method taken by most professionals for how to go with the offline mode and sync with fast performance.

Whether stored in file system (if file system then internal or external?) / as a blob in SQLite, which one is better? Any guidance with codes or links provided would be helpful.
Thank you for your time and support

Answer (score 1):

> Saving images as `Blob` in the DB is never advised.

There is usually no specific thumb rule for your requirement, however, I would like to clarify a few points which can help you in deciding the architecture.

**Point 1:**
App size increases with your code, layout, libraries used, app images etc. If you are talking about images which are to be used frequently within an App, like `App Icons`, `Launcher Icons`,  `Overlays` etc., then these should definitely be added in the source code itself. However, you should optimize such resources before using in your app. Developers usually face challenges in optimizing images (using) for multiple screen sizes and layouts, as this leads to an increase in the app size. Simple logic, the more files you are adding in your source code, the more space it will occupy, leading to bigger app size.

**Point 2:**
If the images which you are referring to, are to be used while the user is browsing on your app, like E-Commerce `Product Images`, then these definitely shouldn't be added in your code at compile time. Since such resources are dynamic and change (add/edit/delete) frequently depending upon the use cases. Rather these are cached and stored locally on the disk.

**General Approach**
The images are downloaded from the server via `API` and saved as files locally, either in Internal Storage or External Storage. Their absolute path, is rather, stored in the `DB` for accessing and indexing. Storing images in the Internal Storage will not increase the app size, however, it will increase the space being used by the app (which is displayed in the `App Info` settings menu). Similarly, storing images in the External Storage will also occupy system storage space, however, will expose such files to other apps too.

You can read about it more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific)

Comment: thanx Atish for the guidance and the link

Answer (score 0):

Atish Agrawal pretty much summed up everything there is to say, but I will add my few words.

Generally speaking, there is plenty of methods to store images, every one of them will take some disk space anyway. Some time ago I've written simple method for storing and uploading images via android to **MS SQL Server database**. I used a cool database feature called [filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) which lets you upload binary data to your table. In android, after taking a picture I was **scaling it down** a bit and then encoding the image file to base array and upload that data to database, one picture was about average 330kB. The cool thing with posting the images into your database is the fact that you don't have to store the images in android anymore - you can just download the wanted image at runtime (downloading and then decoding the byte array)

I hope you find the best fit for your case, happy coding!

Comment: Hey thanx qki,  jus wanted to know when you were scaling it down and encoding, what about the quality when user open it full screen?, and can you plese let me know how you did it or any links? :)